# Circular background of a layout in android

Tags: android

I have 5 buttons in a layout forming a cross structure.
Now I want that the background of this layout should be circle so that it should look as if the buttons are on the circle like you see buttons on TV remote.
I will really appreciate your any answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Set circular image as the background of your layout. As this for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/circular_image"
    ... >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```